# Synonym for man-made, but not by man

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a synonym for man-made (i.e., not naturally occurring) that doesn't imply it was made by humans. "Fabricated" or "constructed" are the closest I've come, but I'm not very happy with either of them. Does anyone have some other suggestions?

Edit: Thanks for all the great suggestions! To clarify a bit further: what I mean by "natural" would be something like a rock, cliff or mountain, a tree or forest, a stream or natural lake. The word I'm looking for would refer to anything made by some creature, be it a human, animal, ghost or alien.

Comment: Why don't you like those words?

Comment: Do you mean something like a bird's nest?

Comment: Something made by aliens?

Comment: I think people have a problem understanding _who_ would have made it, if not man. Can you please give an example?

Comment: [Hubba-wha](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hubba-wha)?

Comment: Basically I'm looking to describe a feature as having been created by something, but not necessarily by humans. It could have been constructed by animals, aliens, or humans, but the feature is definitely not a natural occurence.

Comment: @MattЭллен "Man-made feature" has a ring to it that I miss in "fabricated feature" or "constructed feature".

Comment: Ok, so something 'artificial' probably.

Comment: "Not of natural origin" perhaps

Comment: So you mean something like a bird's nest (created by an animal) - but you also would not say that a bird's nest is a natural occurrence? I think we are going to need a good description of what you consider "natural" or not. An artefact seems to cover what you mean, but they are not made by animals (other than humans). Most people consider bird's nests natural occurrences.

Comment: I'm thinking a rock or canyon are natural occurrences but a bird's nest is manufactured by a bird in that a bunch of twigs didn't fall together, blown about by the wind.

Comment: If not made by man, it's **not** man-made. Please make up your mind :)

Comment: Of course, I get your point. It could be *artificial* or *synthetic* depending on what exactly is meant -- there's a slight difference (significant in some contexts).

Comment: As in, a dam built by a beaver.  While a dam can happen naturally by coincidence (flotsam building up and blocking off the water or landslide, etc), what do you call it when a beaver makes one intentionally.

Comment: Alternatively, what if you're a conspiracy theorist who believes Stonehenge/Pyramids were made by aliens?  They aren't natural, they aren't man made, they're...?

Comment: This question is entirely unclear — it appears to be a guessing game. What objects do you consider to be included in or excluded from this category? Please provide numerous examples. What words have you considered, and why do you consider "fabricated" and "constructed" not good?

Comment: @200_success I had hoped my edit made it clearer? Otherwise Kristina Lopez summed it up pretty well in her comment. As mentioned in my comment above, "fabricated" and "constructed" don't have the same ring as "man-made" to me, but I'm tending towards "fabricated" at the moment.

Comment: I still don't get what your defining criteria are, because you haven't expressed them. Is a honeycomb included in this category? What about honey? Coral? A peapod? A single strand of silk? The question is much less clear than you think.

Comment: @200_success Honeycomb, honey, coral and a strand of silk would definitely be included (they are all made by something, but not man-made), and represent exactly the sort of things I want to express. A peapod is borderline if grown, but I would tend to exclude it. After all, a peapod that was grown by a human isn't really man-made.

Comment: Is 'anthropogenic' the word you are looking for?

Comment: That would be they're explicitly not looking for, since *anthropogenic* means caused or produced by humans. (Or producing humans, in another sense).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Fabricated* or *artificial* are your best bests. In fact, *artificial* is the **opposite** of natural.

> *[Artificial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/artificial)*, **adj**: 
>      not natural or real : made, produced, or done to seem like something natural

Comment: Include supporting references, else it could constitute a comment only.

Comment: Fixed, added a definition with a link

Comment: I still would not consider a bird's nest artificial (unless it were man-made).

Comment: @oerkelens It depends on context. If I were on an alien planet that was unknown to have life, and I found a nest I would certainly report back: "Found evidence of a possible artificial structure."

Comment: @oerkelens Imagine a dam built by a beaver. While a dam can happen naturally by coincidence (flotsam building up and blocking off the water or landslide, etc), what do you call it when a beaver makes one intentionally?  It's not natural, it was built with intent.  It's not man-made...so it's what? **artificial** works well, as in an artificial dam.

Comment: Alternatively, what if you're a conspiracy theorist who believes Stonehenge/Pyramids were made by aliens?  They aren't natural, they aren't man made, they're...?

Comment: @Doc - artificial would work for the aliens maybe. But the OP said he wanted something that did not apply to natural things. I happen to think that animals are part of nature and what they build is natural. That is why I asked for a clearer definition of natural. It's a pity the OP has not clarified what he means.

Comment: @oerkelens if things built by animals are natural, why aren't things built by humans?  We're animals, we're natural, why is a house less natural than a bird nest?  For that matter, if that's how you take things, why wouldn't what an alien built be 'natural'?  They too are 'natural creatures' presumably, and whatever they built would also be a natural process just like the bird's nest.  At this rate, there isn't anything *unnatural*.

Comment: @Doc: thta is a very good question, and the answer will stem from teh answer to "gee, why have we ever made a distinction between man and _other_ animals". Don;t forget that "man is an animal" (in the literal sense) was a sentence that could get you into trouble if you even had the gall to _think_ it, not _that _ long ago...

Answer (score 10):

The term *synthetic* comes to mind, as well as its synonyms *fabricated*, *manufactured*, and *constructed*.

Comment: I trust that the OP can look up the words in a dictionary or thesaurus, and providing the definitions here would just be a waste of space. This is an answer to the question, so it does not belong as a comment. Unless **you** can include supporting references for your suggestion, of course!

Comment: No, not at all. http://english.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your link that dictates that answers without references should be comments. In fact, I seem to recall a meta discussion suggesting that long-winded explanations and copy-pastes from dictionaries are discouraged!

Comment: A bird's nest is not "synthetic", I think? It could be described as fabricated or constructed, but _manufactured_?

Comment: @oerkelens From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic): Synthesis, the combination of two or more parts, whether by design or by natural processes **Furthermore, it may imply being prepared or made artificially, in contrast to naturally.**

Comment: _In contrast to naturally_ - I'm just saying, most people do consider bird's nests a natural occurrence. Calling them non-natural will make some people look weird at you.

Comment: That's up to the OP. He's on the fuzzy line between "natural" and "not natural". The best we can do is provide him words that match his descriptions. His descriptions are up to him.

Comment: Kevin Workman, rather than adding references and supporting quotes in comments, edit them into the question.  Note, I can't reverse my downvote for lack of references until after you edit the question, due to it getting locked in after 5 minutes.

Comment: @ Kevin: From the Help page for [How to Answer:](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) *Links to external resources **are encouraged**, but please add context*. If in fact there's nothing else to say apart from providing a list of candidate words, that does rather suggest the question should be closed rather than answered (ELU isn't a "human-powered" online thesaurus).

Answer (score 3):

Consider ***[made](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/made).***

> 1. Produced or created artificially: *bought some made goods at the local store.*
> 2. artificially produced; not originating in nature: *made fur.*

Comment: Like a canyon made by a river?

Comment: @Beta: It is a different usage. I'm talking about the adjective. Check the definition.

Answer (score 3):

[***artifactual***](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=OPoOkEg4x6cC&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=artifactual+spider+web&source=bl&ots=uS-KIxMUkq&sig=WUeoMOrwfVNoQ0-rxS6cT0KnKS8&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=5G6gU43-K8Pt0gWbt4GICQ&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=artifactual%20spider%20web&f=false)

> "*This includes nonhuman artifacts such as spiders' webs, beavers' dams, and chimpanzees' termite-fishing sticks.*"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the objects you're thinking about are those that might be considered *designed*. *Designed* in the sense that is often contrasted with *evolved*.

A bird's nest or spider's web is constructed, but they are not *designed*. The animals construct them, according to their evolved instincts, without planning or knowledge of their purpose.

Comment: Sure? "not designed ... without planning or knowledge of their purpose?"

Comment: I'll go with that. If we found something on Mars that seemed to have been *designed*, we'd take that as evidence for the existence of ***intelligent** alien life*. If we later found that it was the alien equivalent of a wasp nest, for example (and that the aliens were actually no smarter than wasps), we'd probably stop using that word for their "artefacts".

Comment: That's one sense of *design*. There is another in common use that describes intricate functional arrangements that involved no intelligence or purpose, such as coral reefs or animal anatomy. We can say that the design on a peacock's tail attracts mates, and that our brains were designed to cope with social interaction, without implying any intelligent artists or engineers. **P.S.** Richard Dawkins and Daniel Dennet use the word in those two senses, respectively.

Comment: Additionally, "evolved" used to mean "something that is the result of some design", until Darwin took it and used it to mean the overall change resulting from selection pressure on a population

Answer (score 0):

"Man-made," like "man" and "mankind," has become embroiled in the whole gender-neutral language issue. So it is legitimate to look for variants, especially in contexts where your usage affects how your work is received by its likely audience. I'm sorry that the tone of some of these comments is flippant, because the question deserves a serious answer. Many of the alternatives offered would fit, some obviously better than others in certain contexts. That's the nature of language: there are no true synonyms, and nuances of meaning in similar words make it necessary to think carefully before choosing which to use in a given context.

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is kind of old but what about anthropogenic?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Can you try to include reference or link (that can support your answer) and its essential parts? Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: This is clearly the wrong answer, because it *does* imply made by man. Please read the questions carefully before answering.